# My jasmine tests are far too brittle

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've been Googling this all afternoon but have been struggling to find a viable solution to my problem.

Basically, I've started some Angular development and have a controller of about 700 lines. My spec file is around 2100 lines and I have 100% code coverage. I've been finding that any time I have to change the controller, I have to fix about 5 unit tests. They're not finding me bugs. 
I don't use a TDD methodology, maybe this is the problem? The code gets written and then the tests get written. 
I ask because anywhere I read online, the general consensus is unit testing is great. I'm just not seeing any value to them any minute and they're costing me too much time.

If anyone has any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There is no value return on unit testing. The point of the unit tests is to document how the code was expected to operate. When your tests go beyond that scope they become a burden to maintain, but if done correctly they can be used in the future to resolve issues when an unforeseen operation must take place. They do not find bugs, prevent bugs or improve the quality of code. They just assert that the code does what the programmer was expecting it to do, and sometimes making those asserts requires the code to be written in a test friendly way. That's about it. Don't expect to much from tests.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - I grossly disagree. The amount of bugs tests have revealed to me is huge. They certainly improve code quality by the virtue of forcing you to design your code before writing it. I have written code without tests do to time constraint only to find the code wasn't testable; then on the same goal doing TDD resulted in code that was half the size. Honestly, although I was skeptic and frustrated when started with TDD, I can't imagine writing code otherwise nowadays.

Comment: @Izhaki I think this is just a debate of semantics. Bugs and code quality can often be very opinionated distinctions. Unit tests don't find bugs. They just assert the code works as expected. When the tests all pass the code is aligned with those expectations, but a "bug" is an event that wasn't expected. The test is then updated to handle a new expectation, and the cycle repeats. Code quality and testable code do not correlate. I've seen enough badly written code that have unit tests to know that. Your code quality improved because you've become a better programmer, and tests helped :)

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, not sure what you define as a bug - but my tests often throw javascript errors or just fail, well before you press refresh. In one instance, I had this code that removes an item from an array using for loop, the test revealed that the code doesn't work (taking an item out meant the next item was skipped) - the test caught it although the app runtime execution worked alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Separate your concerns

A 700 lines controller and a 2100 lines spec files pretty much means that you adhere little to the [separation of concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (or the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

This is a common problem in Angular, where developers tend to pollute the scope and controllers, rather than allocating responsibilities to services and directives. A good practice is to have controllers initiate the scope and provide event handlers, but most of the logic should reside in services, unless it specific to the actual view of the controller (reusable view logic goes in directives, reusable 'business' logic goes in services).

In turn, this often translates to high level of dependencies, which evident in the fact that 5 tests are failing with a single change. In theory, proper unit testing means that a single change should only fail a single test; this is hardly the case in practice since we are lazy mocking all the dependencies of a unit, but not a big deal since the dependent failing tests will pass once we fix the problematic code.

## Non TDD tests

Having tests but not following TDD is better than not having tests at all, but little ideal.

Tests generally serve 3 purposes (the 3 Ds):

- **Design** - By writing tests first, you first define what the unit should do, only then implement it.
- **Defence** - By writing tests, you ensure that you can change the code, but not its behaviour.
- **Documentation** - Tests serve as documentation to what units should do: 'It should ...'.

Unless part of TDD, you are missing the **design** bit and most of the documentation bit.

Writing tests as an after thought often doesn't ensure the code is working right, but rather that it works as it does. It is very tempting in post-coding tests to provide a function a certain input, make the test fail but see what was the actual output and make this output the expected output - it doesn't mean that the output is correct, just that it is what it is. This doesn't happen when you write tests first.

Comment: +1 *Writing tests as an after thought often doesn't ensure the code is working right, but rather that it works as it does*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's answered the question very well and you've now got me thinking about the overall design.
I was hoping for something to help me come up with a better approach to my unit testing strategy and think this is a great starting point.